# C or D scales for x15 notes tongue drum?

Tags: scales

I am hoping to get a 15notes tongue drum but need advise on which one to get. Some sites advertised as having C scales and other D scales and I don't know which one to get. Appreciate advice.

Comment: To get the best answer(s), please edit your question to describe how you plan to use the drum.

Comment: I am just a beginner. Haven't played a tongue drum before. Hence seeking an advice before I bought it as it's not a cheap instrument.

Answer (score 0):

Playing it totally in isolation, it won't make much difference. If you want to play with others, it'll help if they're all in the same key.

Comment: Thank you Tim, what key is most commonly played?

Comment: 50:50 on that one! But for beginners there's a lot more music in key C. Best ask the supplier.

Comment: Thank you Tim, that's a great help.  You have helped me decide on which one to get.... 